# How to query the datastore by kind name as string using metadata

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

This will not work, but will illustrate my question:

```
query = "my_model".all()
print query.count()
```

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer to your own question, not as an edit to it.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice. I changed the question and added the answer.

Comment: Upvoted! <!-- Argh minimum comment length -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, by diving into the datastore code.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

model_class = db.class_for_kind("my_model")     # this method is not published
query = model_class.all()
print query.count()
```

db_class_for_kind can only work if the model is already imported. But you can import the model_class :

```
__import__("my_model_path", globals(), locals(), ["my_model"]], -1)
```

db.class_for_kind is not published. See also this feature request: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=800